# How do I attach object onto a body that is attached to a rig?

Tags: animation, mesh, objects, armature, motion-capture

[image: Screenshot of the meshes not connecting]

I'm new to Blender doing a quick animation and some parts of the model not following the rest of the mesh.

I don't know what I did wrong or was it because I was using a model I found online.

Is there a way for me to attach those floating objects to the rest of my rigs? I have tried joining them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> but it didn't work

Comment: These other meshes are probably not parented to the parent armature.  You can see whether there's an armature modifier and vertex groups named after the bones in the armature.  in this case, simply put your armature in the Rest position, and select each, then select the armature and use "Parent >> Armature with Automatic Weights".  So both the character mesh *and* others are children of the armature.   In some cases you may instead want to align the other objects to the character mesh and use a Surface Deform modifier (you can search for topics in this site).

Comment: Select the vertices in Edit mode and assign to the vertex groups they should be part of

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was able to make it work by unjoining all the meshes from each other. However, the camera lens in the middle still refuse to be connected to the rest of the model. I tried parenting it to both camera and the rig (seperately) and joining it doesn't work either. And I don't understand how the vertex grouping work, the mesh seems to already be assign to every bones in the rig. I tried clicking assign on any of those and nothing happens